React condition render before the call
The condition is calling before fetch, so I can't render the image on the page.
I need to set an icon based on the API data.

Call an API for weather data, then set it to weatherData state

Set the weather Icon/image based on the data


Here Icon/image is external, so I use a switch statement to define the icon
import rain from "../src/Images/rain.jpg";
import fog from "../src/Images/fog.jpg";
import snow from "../src/Images/snow.jpg";
import wind from "../src/Images/wind.jpg";
import cloudy from "../src/Images/cloudy.png";
import sn from "../src/Images/sn.jpg";

let newBG;


 useEffect(() => {
    fetchData             // <==fetching data 
  }, []);


  useEffect(() => {
    setbgTheme(newBg);    // <== setting Bg
  }, [newBG]);



switch (weatherData? weatherData.currentConditions.icon: "sn") {
      case "rain":
        newBg = rain;
        break;
      case "fog":
        newBg = fog;
        break;
      case "cloudy":
        newBg = cloudy;
        break;
      case "snow":
        newBg = snow;
        break;
      case "wind":
        newBg = wind;
        break;
      case "sn":
        newBg = sn;
        
    }

Here switch statement is called before the fetch, so I use a setTimeout function for the switch statement.
Still, it is not rendering.

I think using {} as dict will increase readability of your code, compare to switch-case statement. Also it is better to use component state to keep response value you get from the api, and derive icon from it. You don't need setTimeout or anything.
Here is how you can achieve this:
import rain from "../src/Images/rain.jpg";
import fog from "../src/Images/fog.jpg";
import snow from "../src/Images/snow.jpg";
import wind from "../src/Images/wind.jpg";
import cloudy from "../src/Images/cloudy.png";
import sn from "../src/Images/sn.jpg";

// known weather images dict
const weatherImgs = {
 rain,
 fog,
 snow,
 wind,
 cloudy,
 sn
};

function getWeatherImage(data, defaultImage = 'sn') {
  // try to resolve image or fallback to default
  const image = weatherImgs[data?.currentConditions?.icon ?? defaultImage];
  // extra check in case there is value from api  we don't have image for.
  return image ?? weatherImgs[defaultImage];
}

function YourComponent() {
  // storing api response, not image,
  const [data, setData] = useState(null);  

  useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchData() {
      const response = await fetch("your.app/api/method");
      cons json = await response.json();
      setData(json);
    }
    fetchData();
  }, []);

  // resolving image icon 
  const weatherImage = getWeatherImage(data);

  return (
    <img src={weatherImage} />    
  )
}



I had once tried with
<img src= {weatherData? weatherData.currentConditions.icon : snow}>
but the result was string and thus I had to use a switch statement.

what i have suggested is different. in the image map will be stored resolved imports to the images, accessible by the keys from the api. you can check it. const weatherImgs = { snow, wind,  etc..};  <- this is a main thing here

This weatherImgs Object works

This should be inside a single function with async-await or Promise. Let's see a code here:
import rain from "../src/Images/rain.jpg";
import fog from "../src/Images/fog.jpg";
import snow from "../src/Images/snow.jpg";
import wind from "../src/Images/wind.jpg";
import cloudy from "../src/Images/cloudy.png";
import sn from "../src/Images/sn.jpg";

useEffect(() => {
  // use async on the function where we are using the `await` keyword
  const handleFetchDataAndSetImage = async () => {
    // let's wait for the data from API using await
    const { data } = await axios.get("/your/api/endpoint"); // or you can use fetch instead of axios
    // now we have data
    handleSetBg();
  };

  handleFetchDataAndSetImage();
}, []);

const handleSetBg = () => {
  switch (weatherData ? weatherData.currentConditions.icon : "sn") {
    case "rain":
      setBgTheme(rain);
      break;
    case "fog":
      setBgTheme(fog);
      break;
    case "cloudy":
      setBgTheme(cloudy);
      break;
    case "snow":
      setBgTheme(snow);
      break;
    case "wind":
      setBgTheme(wind);
      break;
    case "sn":
      setBgTheme(sn);
      break;
    default:
      setBgTheme(sn);
  }
};


How to add a switch statement inside the setBgThem state?

Updated the full code for you.

The image is set to "sn", the default value. So I remove the weatherData ? condition from the switch statement. Then It shows, "the currentConditions are not defined"

I think weather Data is not readable in the switch statement

You've to show the sample data for weather data at first. What I understand from your code is you're new to this/react probably, so you have to console.log(weatherData) and check to ensure that you're working on the right data.

There is a component of  Hud and I props drill with the weatherData and it work at the same time
weatherData ?   : Loading} */}

The way the Hud component works on the data might not be similar to what you're trying here (eg. switch case). You have to ensure you are switch case-ing the proper API response section because your weather data can be nested array or objects, you've to pick the right parameter for switching.
